# How to find a mongodb collection entry by ObjectId in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have  a mongodb database which contains two connected collections.

The first one has a dataset which looks like this:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5326d2a61db62d7d2f8c13c0"),
"reporttype": "visits",
"country": "AT",
"channel": "wifi",
"_level": NumberInt(3)
}
```

The ObjectId is connected to several datasets in the second collection which look like this:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("54c905662d0a99627efe17a9"),
"avg": NumberInt(0),
"chunk_begin": ISODate("2015-01-28T12:00:00.0Z"),
"count": NumberInt(15),
"max": NumberInt(0),
"min": NumberInt(0),
"sum": NumberInt(0),
"tag": ObjectId("5326d2a61db62d7d2f8c13c0")
}
```

As you can see it the "_id" from the first dataset the same as the "tag" from the second.

I want to write a routine in php which gets the ids from the first collection and finds by them datasets in a certain timeframe in the second collection for deletion.

I get the id from the first collection ok, but I suspect I use it wrongly in the the query for the second collection because nothing is ever found or deleted.

Code looks like this:

```
// select a collection (analog to a relational database's table)
$tagCollection = $db->tags;
$orderCollection = $db->orders;


// formulate AND query
$aTagCriteria = array(
    'reporttype' => new MongoRegex('/[a-z]+/'),
);
// retrieve only _id keys
$fields = array('_id');

$cursor = $tagCollection->find($aTagCriteria, $fields);

$startOfTimeperiod = new MongoDate(strtotime('2015-01-05 00:00:00'));
$endOfTimeperiod = new MongoDate(strtotime('2015-01-07 13:20:00'));

// iterate through the result set
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo '_id: '.$obj['_id'].' | ';
    // Until here all is ok, I get the _id as output.
    $aOrdercriteria = array(
        'tag'  => new MongoId($obj['_id']),
        'date' => array(
            '$lte' => $endOfTimeperiod,
            '$gte' => $startOfTimeperiod
        ),
    );

    $iCount = $orderCollection->count($aOrdercriteria);
    if ($iCount > 0) {
        echo PHP_EOL.$iCount.' document(s) found.'.PHP_EOL;
        $result = $orderCollection->remove($aOrdercriteria);
        echo __FUNCTION__.'|'.__LINE__.' | '.json_encode($result).PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Removed document with ID: '.$aOrdercriteria['tag'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

What is the correct way for the search condition so it looks for tag Objects
with the previously found id?

PS: 
I tried

```
'tag'  => $obj['_id'],
```

instead of

```
'tag'  => new MongoId($obj['_id']),
```

which didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not a PHP user, but I have you confirmed that the _id is a string? Some drivers automatically convert it to an object id.

Comment: var_dump($obj);
Gives me:
array(1) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoId)#10 (1) {
    ["$id"]=>
    string(24) "537c89d51db62d7d2fd1d37d"
  }
}

Comment: As I interpret this $obj['_id'] should be an object.

Comment: It looks like the _id is already a MongoID, so try not casting it to a MongoId when you build your query.

Comment: so 'tag'  => $obj['_id'], should be correct?

Comment: I'd try that. If it doesn't work, I'd then try casting it to a string. If that doesn't work, I'd wait for someone who knows PHP to help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things had to be changed.

The first one was like EmptyArsenal hinted:

```
tag'  => new MongoId($obj['_id']),
```

is wrong since $obj['_id'] is already an object.

So

```
'tag'  => $obj['_id'],
```

is correct.
And if I change my condition  from "date" to "chunk_begin" yahooo.... it works. Stupid me.